# Cannot pass text from LWC to Apex Class

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, js, lightning-components

I'm attempting to pass text from a lightning-textarea to my apex handler. I'm still getting null values for the message, but am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" title="Temp Messaging" icon-name="standard:messaging_conversation" height="400px">
        <lightning-textarea 
           
          max-length="1000"
          name="messageInput" 
          label="Message:" 
          placeholder="Message..."
           
          value={message}
          variant="standard"
        ></lightning-textarea>
        <template lwc:if={response}>
          <p>{response}</p>
        </template>
        <button type="button" label="Send" onclick={handleClick}>Send</button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import TempMessagingComponentHandlerClass from '@salesforce/apex/TempMessagingComponentHandler.tempMessagingComponentHandlerClass';
import SystemModstamp from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SystemModstamp';

export default class TempMessagingComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @track response;
    @track message;
    handleClick(event){
        console.log('Here is the Message ### ');
        TempMessagingComponentHandlerClass({SMS: this.message, accountId: this.recordId})
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Here is the response ### ' + result);
            this.response = result;
            if(this.response == 'Message sent.'){
                this.message = null;
            }
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log('Error occured ### ');
            console.log(error);
        })
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWC has only one way binding - from the javascript -> template.

You can grab the value of the textarea just prior to sending to the server in your handleClick method:

```
let value = this.template.queryselector("lightning-text-area").value;
TempMessagingComponentHandlerClass({SMS: value, accountId: this.recordId}).then().... etc
```

I haven't used a changehandler because this may cause an endless loop and crash your browser (potentially)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle changes on your text area, otherwise your LWC doesn't know about the changes made in the text area.

see also:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getter

in your case, you'd create a `handleChange` function to update your message variable before you make the call to your apex method.

e.g.

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.message = event.detail.value;
}
```

then update your `lightning-textarea` to have an `onchange` handler.

e.g.

```
<lightning-textarea 
       
      max-length="1000"
      name="messageInput" 
      label="Message:" 
      placeholder="Message..."
      value={message}
      variant="standard"
      onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-textarea>
```